# Create a Patch file excluding some files

Tags: git, diff, patch

I want to create a patch file that will only patch certain files from dir2 to dir1. Both are git repos of the same project, however dir2 contains a modified highly modified version of the first. I want to only patch the changes made to certain files. dir2 also has extra files dir1 does not have. 
Mainly there are config files in dir1 I do not want dir2 to change, as these have changes that will break my local configuration. How can I exclude changing these particular files?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `git diff <commit1> <commit2> -- <file1> <file2> <file3> ...`.

Comment: Consider whether it makes more sense to have those configuration files share their common elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the files which dir1 and dir2 share...

```
cd dir1
tree -aif --noreport > dir1.out
cd dir2
tree -aif --noreport > dir2.out
cat dir1.out dir2.out | sort | uniq -d > shared.out
```

(You can probably use `ls` to get the listing, but I can never get it right)

To get the changes to dir2 files which are also in dir1 since a given commit...

```
cd dir2
git diff <commit> -- `cat shared.out` > dir2.patch
```

Then apply that patch to dir1 using `patch` and the appropriate `-p` flag.  Anything you don't want to change, use `git checkout <dir1/somefile>` to undo the changes.  Then add and commit as normal.