# Remove changes to a particular file from a patch-file

Tags: patch

I have a patch file that changes many files. It accidentally includes changes to some files that it shouldn't. I can manually remove all mention of these files from the patch to yield a correct patch file, but this is a tedious process.

How can I programmatically (standard *nix tools) remove all mentions of a file from a patch?

---

Note: I do not have the Git setup that the patch was originally generated from, so I am only interested in solutions that work just on the patch file. Given the structure of these files this should be feasible.

This question concerns Git: [Create a Patch file excluding some files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096972/create-a-patch-file-excluding-some-files)

This question concerns TFS: [How to remove particular file of a changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924136/how-to-remove-particular-file-of-a-changeset)

Answer (score 5):

Many linux distributions provide [patchutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/) which includes several utilities for this:

> Filterdiff will select the portions of a patch file that apply to files matching (or, alternatively, not matching) a shell wildcard.
>
> Splitdiff separates out patches from a patch file so that each new patch file only alters any given file once. In this way, a file containing several incremental patches can be split into individual incremental patches.